# SQL schema design: two tables vs adding columns to the same table

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

This question is about design decision, hence might be a bit opinionated:

Imagine you are designing database for a car dealer where they ONLY auction cars. Some cars are for display only, and some cars are to be sold in auction.

I have a `Car` entity with 10 attributes: `ID, Model, Mode, YearMade, IsDisplayOnly...`.

Now, I want to add selling price and selling notes to those cars that are for sale (i.e. `IsDisplayOnly = false`)

I image that there are two ways this can be done:

1. Add `Price` and `PriceNotes` columns into the `Car` table, knowing that they are always null for `IsDisplayOnly = true` cars, and those that haven't been sold at auction yet.
2. Add a new table `SaleInfo` with 3 columns: `CarID, Price, PriceNotes` where `CarID` is the PK and also FK pointing to the `ID` column in the `Car` table.

Which option would align most with the best schema design practice? Why?

Comment: Based on the provided info.... why complicate it? Just put it in the same table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what if it has 10 attributes? I think adding columns might be good too. But should we at one point think that there is too much info there and split it into 2 tables? What's the general rule for deciding when to split a table into 2?

Comment: You should add it to the same table to reduce the unnecessary complexity. Don't worry, the complexity will come later, so better to make it not complex from the beginning

Comment: splitting a table into 2 like that is called "vertical partitioning". The general rule I live by is "don't make it complicated unless you have to". Also don't overthink design and get into analysis paralysis. Anyway google "sql vertical partitioning" for more opinions

Answer (score 1):

You should have one car for cars and the attributes of cars.  You should have a separate table for the cars for auction.

Why?  These are different entities.  Your problem definition suggests an auction table.  That auction table should have a foreign key references to the cars that are available for auction.  A separate table ensures that that foreign key reference is valid.

There are some other reasons that are not apparent in your simplified example.  Notes and prices might change over time, so they should be going into a history table.  Display cars have other attributes, like the period of time when they are on display and how they are ultimately disposed of.  This suggests that they too have particular attributes.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use three tables:

-The first to store all the makes and models of the cars. As well as their costs(eg Honda something or other selling for X amount of money)

-The second to store the details of the individual vehicles, containing a foreign key to the primary key of one of the Make/Model stored in the first table, as well as individual details such as the color, VIN no. etc. As well as whether they can be sold or not.

-The third table would contain the details of each individual purchases, linked to the table containing each individual vehicle, this would be linked to the table containing the details of each individual vehicle, with each purchase connected to a single instance. On the table of vehicles.

The advantages for this layout is that you are actually going to end up using less storage space in the long run, as instead of having the same three fields (The make, model and year) repeating for every vehicle, you will only have a single field to represent that data instead of multiple redundant fields. Another advantage will be searching, as if you are searching for details of individual vehicles of the same brand/type, you will be able to search using only one field, the key linked to the table containing the make and model. This would drastically decrease search times and improve the effectiveness of the system overall.